# React Native : nested JSON object shallow copy (reference) not working

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, reference, shallow-copy

I have a nested JSON objects that looks like `{"name", "children": [JSON objects]}`.
I am trying to add a new child to the object found with a variable `path`, an array of names.

My code doesn't work in my React Native app, however it does in the Chrome console, which makes me really confused. Does it have to do with React Native and if so how can i work it out ?

Code uploaded in the Google Console which yields the expected result : `j.children[0].children[0] = 'test'` :

```
let j = {"name": "root", children: [{"name": "tag1", children: []}]};
let res = j;
const path = ["tag1"];

for (const name of path) {
   for (const child of res.children) {
      if (child.name == name) {
         res = child;
         break;
      }
   }
}
res.children.push("test");
console.log(j);
```

The same code, wrapped in a React Native app, tested on an Android emulator (PIXEL_5_API_30), yields
`{"children": [{"children": [Array], "name": "tag1"}], "name": "root"}` which is not the expected behavior (`[Array]` means empty array).

```
export default function App() {

const test = () => {
    let j = {"name": "root", children: [{"name": "tag1", children: []}]};
    let res = j;
    const path = ["tag1"];

    for (const name of path) {
      for (const child of res.children) {
        if (child.name == name) {
          res = child;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    res.children.push("test");
    console.log(j);
}

return (
    <View>
      <Button title="test" onPress={test} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that your code does not have _any_ JSON in it. If it's not a string you're talking about JS objects, not JSON.

Comment: What does this have to do with shallow copies? You're not copying anything in your code!

Comment: "*[Array] means empty array*" - are you sure there? Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(j))` instead

Comment: Yes im surely mistaking js objects with json, I'll read about that. I'll try it as soon as I can @Bergi, although if arrays were displayed as [Array], we wouldn't see the "tag1" object in the console output but just [Array]. It's not a shallow copy you're right, but since there's no way to explicitly make a reference to variables in js, I mistake reference and shallow copy in js, surely not right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay after checking, indeed [Array] is not the empty array, and the code works as intended. It seems React Native only display array up to one depth. I don't know how to close my question without deleting it though. Thanks @Bergi !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after checking, indeed `[Array]` is not the empty array, and the code works as intended. It seems React Native only display array up to one depth.